# Google Map Timeline slider

Tags: jquery, google-maps, kml

What's the best way I can take multiple KML files (each representing a different date) and create a google map with a slider?

Comment: What is the function of the slider? To zoom in? To select data from a specific date?

Comment: Each tic of the slider would then select a different KML file and display.   I want to use KML files (which I'm creating from a database) b/c I want to allow visitors to download each dated KML.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

try http://code.google.com/p/timemap/

Answer (score 1):

You can use JQuery UI slider and change layers. 
1. Each Year is one and must be separate table.
2. Slide between layers (years).

[Here is a demo of my solution](http://piotrkrosniak.github.io/)

[and code on GitHub](https://github.com/PiotrKrosniak/FusionTablesSlider)

Comment: It is helpful to include some code in your answer rather than just a link, especially should that destination ever become invalid

Comment: A year from now if those links break, this answer will become useless for future visitors.